# ObjectDoesNotExist vs. .filter().first() and check for None

Tags: django, django-models

In Django 1.6 they introduced `.first()` to get the first element of a queryset. [[Source]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first)

Now there are 2 ways to get a single element:

```
user_id = 42
try:
    obj = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    raise Exception("Invalid user id given")
```

and:

```
user_id = 42
obj = User.objects.filter(id=user_id).first()
if not obj:
    raise Exception("Invalid user id given")
```

Following the pythonic way to ask for forgiveness, the first one would be more appreciated way to use.
However, the second one might be easier to understand and it is one line shorter.

**Q1:** Is there any difference in speed between these two code snippets?

**Q2:** Which one is the preferred way to get a single object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two have different semantics and different gaurantees. The main difference is how they handle multiple matching objects.

`.get()` will raise an exception if multiple objects match the given query. You should therefore use `.get()` to fetch an item based on a unique property (such as `id`) or set of properties.

`.first()` will return the first item, based on the defined ordering, if multiple objects match the given query. Use this to filter on non-unique properties, when you need a single item, the first one based on some (possibly undefined) ordering.

So while `.get()` guarantees that exactly one item matches the query, `.first()` only guarantees that it returns the first item based on the given ordering.

How they handle a missing object is more a case of semantics. It is trivial to convert an exception to `None` or the other way around. While you might save a single line here and there, I wouldn't base my decision to use one over the other on this. The performance difference is negligible as well, and probably depends on the results of the query.